# Having trouble with 'while' loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I'm new with javascript, and I'm having some trouble understanding why this code doesn't execute:

```
var weight;

wight=parseInt(prompt("Please, enter weight");

while(weight>0);

{ 
  if (weight>199 && weight<300);
{

  document.write("Tax will be" + weight*5);
}

  else 
{

  document.write("Tax will be" + weight*10);
}
}
```

Edit: I'm sorry, I mispelled some 'weights' while writing down the code here. Either way, that's not the problem. When I run this in google chrome, it just doesn't prompt. And when it prompted, it doesn't execute the 'if' statement.

Comment: You have a semicolon after your while. Remove it.

Comment: You're also alternating between `weight` and `wight`.

Comment: All answers are correct and you can also find your self by checking console at firebug

Comment: Semicolons mean something. They aren't just decorative elements you sprinkle through your code to make it look pretty.

Comment: Did any answer solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
while (wight>0);
```

The semicolon effectively makes that loop: while wight is greater than 0, do nothing. This forces an infinite loop, which is why the rest of your code doesn't execute.

Also, 'wight' is *not* the same as 'weight'. This is another error.

Furthermore, if you change that line to `while (weight > 0)`, you will still have an infinite loop, because the code that then executes does not alter 'weight' - thus, it will *always* be greater than 0 (unless a number less than 0 was entered at the prompt, in which case it won't execute at all).

What you want is:

```
var weight;
weight=parseInt(prompt("Please, enter weight")); // Missing parenthesis
// Those two lines can be combined:
//var weight = parseInt(prompt("Please, enter weight"));

while(weight>0)
{ 
    if (weight>199 && weight<300)// REMOVE semicolon - has same effect - 'do nothing'
    {
        document.write("Tax will be" + weight*5);
        // above string probably needs to have a space at the end:
        // "Tax will be " - to avoid be5 (word smashed together with number)
        // Same applies below
    }
    else 
    {
        document.write("Tax will be" + weight*10);
    }
}
```

That is syntactically correct. You still need to either change the while condition, or alter 'weight' within that loop, to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: Also there's a missing close brace here: `weight=parseInt(prompt("Please, enter weight");` should be `weight=parseInt(prompt("Please, enter weight"));`

Answer (score -1):

spelling of weight :

```
while (wight>0);

while (weight>0);
```

also in

```
document.write("Tax will be" + wight*10);

document.write("Tax will be" + weight*10);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var weight;

weight=parseInt(prompt("Please, enter weight"));

while (weight>0)
{ 
  if (weight>199 && weight<300)
{
  document.write("Tax will be" + weight*5);
}
  else 
{
  document.write("Tax will be" + weight*10);
}
}
```